# Drift in terraform state for RDS due to maintainence window

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, hashicorp

I was trying to update the storage of the RDS using the terraform codes. The tfe apply showed successful but the change went to AWS console in the maintainence window. I applied the change immediately from AWS console considering that the tfe apply is successful and state must be updated. Now my codebase has the latest value for the database storage and my actual db also has the new storage but the state file still shows the older value. Probably its waiting for the maintainence window to update the change. Now the maintainence window doesnt show any pending change since I applied manually.

Is there a way to fix this drift between the terraform state and actual storage.

Comment: I would try running `terraform apply --refresh-only`

Comment: The terraform codes are run by jenkins automated pipeline...Not sure how can I manually run this refresh on db

Comment: Well that's what you need to do to fix the drift. Or you can just run another `apply` through your pipeline and see if that clears it up.

Comment: I tried running the tfe plan...but it says some object have been changed outside the  terraform. But the plan is says no change in infra so its not allowing terraform apply.

Comment: Do you think adding apply_immediately tag to tfe codes can do state refresh